# How to add an new value to an existing json array?

Tags: python, arrays, json

My json structure is like this:

```
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "tag": "greeting",
            "patterns": [
                "Hi there",
                "How are you",
                "Is anyone there?",
                "Hey",
                "Hola",
                "Hello",
                "Good day"
            ],
            "responses": [
                "Hello, thanks for asking",
                "Good to see you again",
                "Hi there, how can I help?"
            ],
            "context": [""]
        },
```

My intention to append a new pattern or response under this tag which is already existing in an array.

```
tgname = request.form['tags']
x = request.form['newres']

with open('intents.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for t in data["intents"]:
    if t['tag'] == tgname:

        temp1 = data['responses']
        temp1.append(x)

        with open(filename,'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
```

I am getting `keyword error:'responses'`. How to resolve this?

Comment: `responses` if not a top-level, key it is inside `t`, so `t['responses']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` variable contains the entire json object and therefor does not have access to `responses`, only to `intents`.
Instead you should use the `t` variable inside your `for` loop since it iterates across each json object inside the `intents` list.

```py
for t in data["intents"]:
    if t['tag'] == tgname:

        # Correct:
        temp1 = t['responses']
        temp1.append(x)

        with open(filename,'w') as f: 
            json.dump(data, f)
```